# Calcular cuanto tiempo tarda un usuario en volver a reingresar

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

Como puedo calcular cuanto tiempo tarda un usuario en volver a ingresar a la institución, supongamos que tengo una `tabla1` con los siguientes campos `id|num_identificacion|fecha_ingreso` y necesito hacer una sub-consulta para agregar la siguiente fecha en que el usuario ingreso, tengo un ejemplo con estos datos:

```
id|num_identificacion|fecha_ingreso

1|1010|20/01/2020

2|2020|21/01/2020

3|3030|22/01/2020

4|1010|23/01/2020

5|4040|24/01/2020

6|1010|25/01/2020

7|5050|26/01/2020

8|2020|27/01/2020

9|3030|28/01/2020

10|1010|29/01/2020
```

y requiero un resultado similar a este:

```
id|num_identificacion|fecha_ingreso|fecha_reingreso|dias_espera

1|1010|20/01/2020|23/01/2020|3

2|2020|21/01/2020|27/01/2020|6

3|3030|22/01/2020|28/01/2020|6

4|1010|23/01/2020|25/01/2020|2

5|4040|24/01/2020|sin reingreso|

6|1010|25/01/2020|29/01/2020|4

7|5050|26/01/2020|sin reingreso|

8|2020|27/01/2020|sin reingreso|

9|3030|28/01/2020|sin reingreso|

10|1010|29/01/2020|sin reingreso|
```

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL estás utilizando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas MySQL 8.0 o superior, puedes valerte de la [función de ventana](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) [`lead()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) para obtener el valor de la `fecha_reingreso`.

Luego, de la función [`datediff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) para calcular el número de días de espera y finalmente de [`coalesce`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) para integrar la cadena `'sin regreso'` para los casos donde no hay un registro de ingreso posterior.

Ensamblado todo en una consulta, quedaría así:

```
select   a.id
       , a.num_identificacion
       , a.fecha_ingreso
       , lead(a.fecha_ingreso) over (partition by a.num_identificacion order by a.fecha_ingreso) fecha_reingreso
       , coalesce(datediff(lead(a.fecha_ingreso) over (partition by a.num_identificacion order by a.fecha_ingreso), a.fecha_ingreso), 'sin regreso') dias_espera
  from tabla1 a
 order by a.id;
```

Lo que, con tus datos de ejemplo, retorna:

```
id      num_identificacion      fecha_ingreso   fecha_reingreso dias_espera
1       1010                    2020-01-20      2020-01-23      3
2       2020                    2020-01-21      2020-01-27      6
3       3030                    2020-01-22      2020-01-28      6
4       1010                    2020-01-23      2020-01-25      2
5       4040                    2020-01-24                      sin regreso
6       1010                    2020-01-25      2020-01-29      4
7       5050                    2020-01-26                      sin regreso
8       2020                    2020-01-27                      sin regreso
9       3030                    2020-01-28                      sin regreso
10      1010                    2020-01-29                      sin regreso
10 rows
```

Puedes crear el esquema así:

```
create table tabla1(
    id                    int primary key
  , num_identificacion    int
  , fecha_ingreso         date
);

insert into tabla1 values
  ( 1, 1010, '2020-01-20')
, ( 2, 2020, '2020-01-21')
, ( 3, 3030, '2020-01-22')
, ( 4, 1010, '2020-01-23')
, ( 5, 4040, '2020-01-24')
, ( 6, 1010, '2020-01-25')
, ( 7, 5050, '2020-01-26')
, ( 8, 2020, '2020-01-27')
, ( 9, 3030, '2020-01-28')
, (10, 1010, '2020-01-29');
```

He dejado [este fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da98154a088084e39d27d80ddfe037ba) para que lo pruebes en vivo.

## mySQL 5.6

Si utilizas las versiones antiguas de mySQL, puedes:

- Utilizar tablas derivadas para realizar los cálculos, en mi solución hay dos tablas derivadas anidadas, `q1` y `q2`.
- Valerte de variables para *arrastrar* el valor de la fecha de reingreso, recorriendo el conjunto de datos en orden orden cronológico inverso, tomando en cuenta siempre primero el campo `num_identificacion`
- En la consulta final, siempre me valgo de la función `datediff()` para entregar el número de días y `coalesce()` para entregar el texto deseado cuando no hay reingreso.

```
select   q2.id
       , q2.num_identificacion
       , q2.fecha_ingreso
       , q2.fecha_reingreso
       , coalesce(datediff(q2.fecha_reingreso, q2.fecha_ingreso), 'sin reingreso') dias_espera
  from (
        select   q1.id
               , q1.num_identificacion
               , q1.fecha_ingreso
               , q1.NumFila
               , q1.old_numID
               , case
                   when q1.old_numID = q1.num_identificacion then q1.old_fechaI
                 end fecha_reingreso
          from (
                select   t1.id
                       , t1.num_identificacion
                       , t1.fecha_ingreso
                       , case 
                           when @old_numID = t1.num_identificacion then @numFila := @numFila + 1 
                           else @numFila := 1 
                         end NumFila
                       , @old_numID old_numID
                       , @old_fechai old_fechaI
                       , @old_numID := t1.num_identificacion ignorar1
                       , @old_fechai := t1.fecha_ingreso ignorar2
                  from tabla1 t1
                       cross join (select @old_numID := null, @numFila := 0) a
                 order by t1.num_identificacion, t1.fecha_ingreso desc
                ) q1    
        order by q1.num_identificacion, q1.NumFila
        ) q2
order by q2.id
```

En mi prueba básica, la consulta entrega el mismo resultado que la anterior.

En mi opinión, la solución es menos elegante y el mantenimiento de esta consulta más complejo... recomendaría utilizar la primera siempre que sea posible.

He dejado también un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/863a3b/29) si quieres probarlo.

Comment: Gracias amigo era justo lo que necesita

Comment: alguna alternativa para versiones de mysql 5 ?

Comment: Dejé una que corre en 5.6, espero que funcione también en alguna versión anterior, pero no lo he probado.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `datediff()` para saber la diferencia entre dos fechas. Sin embargo necesitas hacer un `UPDATE` tomando los valores de la misma tabla, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
UPDATE tabla1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT datediff(NOW(), fecha_ingreso) AS diff FROM tabla1 WHERE id = 1) AS t2
SET t1.dias_espera = t2.diff, t1.fecha_reingreso = NOW()
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Solo necesitarías definir si buscaras por `id` o por `num_identificacion`, así como si usaras la fecha actual con `NOW()` o enviaras una fecha en especifico.

Comment: en realidad lo que busco es una consulta ya que no puedo modificar la base de datos

Comment: Puedes probar con un ejemplo similar como esta en el SELECT que mencioné si necesitas solo saber la diferencia entre la fecha de ingreso y reingreso. Saludos.